# I'm trying to update value of a field from client script

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to send a email using form and also save the history of all the email. and I have a field in database named success to track if the email has send or not. How to update values of a field from client script based on user activities or email sent status.

```
var success = app.models.ChangeSystem.fields.Success.possibleValues;
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error){
           status.text = error.message;
           success = False;
                                     })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
           status.text = 'Email sent';
           success = True;
           clearEmailForm();
  })
  .sendEmailMessage(to, subject, msg);
```

Here success is a field in my database. My script is sending email. and update the 
I was expecting to update the value of success which has two possible values(I'm fine if I have to change the field to boolean). Anyone can give me a direction how to achieve that?? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your script actually doing? What is 'success' in your script, is it a previously declared variable that is pointing to one of your fields? It seems that you are not including all of your code. In order to help you I think you need to edit your question with some information that appears to be missing.

Comment: I've updated my question. @MarkusMalessa

Comment: Found your problem. `.possibleValues` is a read-only list from all client and server scripts, it can only be edited in App Maker editing session. Instead try `var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem;` and replace the 'success' lines of code with `success.Success = false; // or true` and see if that correctly changes your field value. Also if your Success Field is a string then it would need to be 'True' or 'False' to recognize it as text instead of a boolean, or as you stated change that field to a boolean.

Comment: tried this. it is not giving me any errors, but it is not updating my field values either. Is there any other way to do that??

Comment: Is your datasource by chance set to manual save? That is the only the thing I can think of why it would not update the value.

Comment: no It's not in manual save mode. I have a default value saved whatever I do, it is just giving me the default value which I saved as false.

Comment: ```var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem;
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error){
           status.text = error.message;
           success.Success = false;
                                     })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
           status.text = 'Email sent';
           success.Success = true;
           clearEmailForm();
  })
  .sendEmailMessage(to,subject, msg); ```

Comment: What does `status.text` point to? Presumably it's a label, but I have found at times that when trying to set text in client script and there is an error with that particular part it will not show in the console. So maybe it has an error when setting that property and therefore it's not moving to the next line of code.

Comment: ``` var status = app.pages.Email.descendants.EmailStatus; ```  status.text is an label which is invisible and show up when email is sent or some error occurs. I have tried to save the success field before save the text field. But I'm getting same error.

Comment: Just thought of something, but is this function implemented along with a creation of a new record in a particular datasource?

Comment: Yes, You're right. I'm trying to create a new record and set up it's success value field..

Comment: Posted an answer, hopefully that will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you are creating a record that has a dependency on an email being sent then you need to implement the email function and call back inside the success function of the record being created like so:

Lets say you have a form with a button that creates a record that has an email sent status field then your 'Submit Button' should have the following code:

```
var status = app.pages.Email.descendants.EmailStatus;
widget.datasource.createItem({
  success: function(result) {
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(function(e) {
        status.text = e.message;
        result.Success = false;
      })
      .withSuccessHandler(function() {
        status.text = 'Email sent';
        result.Success = true;
      })
      .sendEmailMessage(to, subject, msg);
  },
  failure: function(error) {
    status.text = error.message;
  }
});
```