# how to update database fields by checking the success of sending email?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to make a form in google app maker. I've created a form. which has a "preview(save" button, It will create a new item and I have a field named "status". The default value of this field is "draft". In the next page I have a "sent email" button. This page won't create any new item. It'll send the email and if the email deliver is successful then it'll update the field of status from "draft" to "completed"

This is my client script

```
function sendMessage(to, subject, msg){
// some part is omitted 
var status = app.popups.NotificationDialog.descendants.notificationText;
var success = app.datasources.ChangeSystem;

google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error){
          // success.Success = "draft"
           status.text = error.message;

                                     })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result){

            status.text = 'sent';
            success.Success = "completed";
            clearEmailForm();
  })
  .sendEmailMessage(to, subject, msg); 
}
```

and this is my email sent button function

```
var widgets = app.pages.Email.descendants;
var to;
var subject = widgets.systemName.value 
var msg =  "Description:\n\t\t"        + widgets.Objective.value; 
          widgets.EmailStatus.text = 'Sending email...';
sendMessage(to, subject, msg);
```

So far I am successful to send the email also I have created and saved all fields. But the problem is after sending the email the "status" field doesn't update. It remains the same as default value "draft". my expected result is after pressing the send button it will update one of the existing fields.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061468/im-trying-to-update-value-of-a-field-from-client-script. Although I suppose the answer provided here does not quiet meet the requirement. Still think though that the datasource may be in manual save mode especially since you mention a 'Save' button here. I would also advise to include the rest of your code like your success and status variables since you don't include how those are defined.

Comment: Already tried that one, didn't work. Also, My database isn't in manual save mode. I've updated my code part.

Comment: The last thing I can think of without additional detail is that your possible values for your Success field does not include 'completed' or there is a difference in the spelling from your possible value entry to what you are setting in your script.

Comment: See the updated answer. Either which way I think the error was omitting `.item` in the success variable.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional thinking on this topic I think I found the problem. Here is some updated code assuming your send email button is the same inherited datasource as the field that you are trying to update.

```
var success = widget.datasource.item;
google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(function(error) 
    status.text = error.message;
    success.Success = 'draft';
  })
  .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
    status.text = 'Email sent';
    success.Success = 'completed';
    clearEmailForm();
  })
  .sendEmailMessage(to,subject, msg);
```

Comment: Worked Like a charm.. Thank you very much.. Btw I have to add those part in client script. Adding those in submit button didn't work.